# Acer BeTouch E130 notification bar keyboard

Tags: 2.1-eclair, notification-bar

I've bought the Acer BeTouch E130 and updated it to **Android 2.1**. Therefore, I'd like to know if there's a way to trigger the **Top notification bar** from the physical keyboard rather than tapping on it (which works 10 times out of a 100 because of its size, and my finger's size...).

Comment: I'm not certain there is a way to activate the notification bar via an app, ROM, etc. However, if you want to determine whether you can do it programmatically, you are better off asking that part of your question on http://stackoverflow.com (that site is for software development, this one is for android users).

Comment: On one of the home screen replacements (LauncherPro I think) there was added a "Notifications" entry when you pressed the menu button on the home screen.

Comment: @Miloud: Please do not include "tags" in your titles. I've edited this one out.

Comment: @Everett it wasn't intended to be a tag I just wanted my question to be as concise as possible over the title reading ;) but noted. 

@Everett thanks i'm -on a check this LaunchPro

Comment: Also, in Zeam (another home screen replacement), you can set one of the built-in gestures to open the notification drawer. So, it must be possible.

Answer (score 1):

on the home screen ...
push settings button and use the trackball to chose "notifications"